# Upload Image on Firebase Storage didn't work

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, firebase-storage

I'm new in react-native , and i want to upload an image to Firebase Storage, but i have a warning.

[image]

And this is the code:

```js
  const postBook = async () => {
    console.warn("uploaded");
    const uploadUri = image;
    let filename = uploadUri.substring(uploadUri.lastIndexOf("/") + 1);

    setUploading(true);

    try {
      await storage().ref(filename).putFile(uploadUri);
      console.log("traga");
      setUploading(false);
      Alert.alert(
        "Image uploaded",
        "Your image has been uploaded to the Firebase Cloud Storage"
      );
    } catch (e) {
      console.log(e);
    }

    setImage(null);
  };
```

Console.warn is working in the app, and the function is
called by the button.

Comment: It seems that you have a problem with `uploadUri`. What do you get if you check its value?

Answer (score 0):

Try using the upload method and specify the path first.

```
const filePath = "your-images-path";
const fileRef = this.storage.ref(filePath);
const task = this.storage.upload(filePath, file);
```